# Output is 'undefined' on retrieval of array field from Mongodb using node.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb

I want to fetch an array which consists of id referenced from a different collection.

Region

```
var list1 = {
    region_id: 'us-east-1',
    region_name:'US East(N.Virginia)',
    os_type: 'linux',
    inst_name: {$ref : "instance", $id: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38]},
    prov_id: 'aws'
};
```

Instance

```
 {
     inst_id: 1,
     inst_type: 't2.micro',
     vcpu: 1,
     memory_gib: 1,
     prov_id: 'aws'
 };

  {
     inst_id: 2,
     inst_type: 't2.small',
     vcpu: 1,
     memory_gib: 2,
     prov_id: 'aws'
 };
```

My node.js code

```
 region.findOne(({
     $and: [{
         "region_id": "ap-east-1"
     }, {
         "os_type": "sles"
     }]
 }),
 function (err, result) {
     if (err) {
         throw (err);
     } else {
         var arr = result.inst_name;
         var arrli = arr.$id;
         console.log(arrli);
     }
 });
```

The output for this is printed as 'undefined' in console. How do I fetch the array from $id field as it is?

Comment: Can you `console.log(result)`?

Comment: That's a `DBRef` right? You are going to have problems with using `DBRef` and you really should not be using it.

Comment: Yes, It displays the particular document which matches with "ap-east-1" and "sles".
{ _id: 55daf10e132a6ea80fa6a12a,
  region_id: 'ap-east-1',
  region_name: 'South America(Sao Paulo)',
  os_type: 'sles',
  inst_name:
   { _bsontype: 'DBRef',
     namespace: 'instance',
     oid: [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 29, 30 ],
     db: undefined },
  prov_id: 'aws' }

Comment: @BlakesSeven Is there any other way to reference one collection in another?

Comment: How about looking into ["mongoose"](http://mongoosejs.com/) or at the very least the "client side" referencing it employs. This is all covered in the core documentation on [Manual References](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/database-references/#manual-references). The main problem here is that `$` prefixes are not allowed anymore and are considered "reserved" for operators.

Comment: @BlakesSeven It works on mongo shell. But not with node.js. This is the query I tried on mongo shell
     var inst = db.region.findOne({$and: [{"region_name": "Brazil South"},{"os_type": "windows"}]}).inst_name.$id;
db.instance.find({ "inst_id": { "$in": inst } });

Comment: Well for starters, node.js uses "callbacks" or maye "promises" to deal with asynchronous responses, so there is a big difference there as you seem to be expecting a "synchonous" response just lke the shell. I am really emploring you to look into alternate means for your "references" since `DBRef()` was a bad idea to begin with that everyone involved is really trying to wash their hands of.